# Why my Image from remote server appeared smaller?

Tags: android, image

I have an image in one of my Activities, and this is control by a remote server. My problem is, whenever I use this code, the image appears smaller on my phone but not in emulator. I want the image to appear just like its original size. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong. Thanks in advance!

```
ImageView imgView =(ImageView )findViewById(R.id.image01);
Drawable drawable = LoadImageFromWebOperations("http://www.yourimage.com");
imgView.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);

    }

    private Drawable LoadImageFromWebOperations(String url) {
        try {
            InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(url).getContent();
            Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src name");
            return d;
            }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exc="+e);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Here is my xml:

```
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/image01"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try changing drawable to Bitmap with commant:

```
(BitmapDrawable)drawable).getBitmap())
```

and change the size of bitmap

```
b = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(((BitmapDrawable)drawicon).getBitmap(), your_size_W, your_size_H, true);
```

and use: `setImageBitmap` to show in ImageView